# EXCEL: Formula to Calculate the Standard Deviation for Subsets of a Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have a range containing 200 values.

I'd like a formula that calculates the standard deviation of the top X of those values, where X is a value in a cell. For example, the standard deviation of the top 50 cells.

I'd also like a formula that, given a value in the range, calculates the standard deviation of the next X values in the range. For example, for value 15, the standard devation of values 15 - 15+x.

I feel confident that I can get the second formula on my own, given the first, but I'm blanking on how to do a standard deviation in this context. Average was a lot easier, using `SUMIF` and `LARGE`.

Comment: Is filtering an option?

Comment: I would prefer not to filter, but could if I had to.

Comment: You should be able to do the first one using STDEV with OFFSET to pick out the range that you want

Comment: The second one the same way if I understand correctly - i.e. STDEV of cells in rows 15 to 25 if X is 10 and they start in row 1

Comment: Yes, but I don't want the rows, I want the top sorted values. The data is unordered.

Comment: Ah, I understand now, yes that's more difficult.

Comment: In principle you can use the fact that STDEV ignores empty cells and set all cells that are not in the top 50 to blanks in an array, but I don't think it would work if you had ties so I don't have an immediate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the first part would look something like this:-

```
=STDEV(LARGE(A2:A11,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&D2))))
```

where A2:A11 contains some test data and D2 contains how many, starting from the largest, you want to use in your calculation for which I am indebted to [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/find-the-top-10-values-in-an-excel-range-without-sorting/)

It's an array formula so has to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you had a certain value in your data (specified in D3) and wanted the stdev of that value and the next n-1 values in descending order (n specified in D4), the formula would look like this:-

```
=STDEV(LARGE(A2:A11,ROW(INDIRECT(RANK(D3,A1:A10)&":"&(RANK(D3,A1:A10)+D4-1)))))
```

If on the other hand you wanted to get the stdev of values between certain limits (specified in D5 and D6) you could use the original idea of setting non-used values to blanks using the following:-

```
=STDEV(IF((A2:A11>=D5)*(A2:A11<=D6),A2:A11,""))
```

So this example gives the same answer (stdev of 5 highest numbers) three different ways.

[image]

Comment: I'll leave the second part as an exercise for the student for now - probably using RANK but also some sample data would help because I'm still not 100% certain if you mean 10 values following value 15 in decreasing order or values in range 15-25.

Comment: This looks promising. I'll investigate it further when I get home this evening. Thanks for the help.